# Error al invocar llamada al sistema mediante write

Tags: c

Intento hacer una llamada al sistema con la palabra write pero el compilador tira error y dice que error:

> *passing argument 1 of 'write' makes integer from pointer without a
>   cast*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    uint64_t segundos;

    segundos = time(NULL);
    write(stdout, "Segundos desde 1970: %d",segundos);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la función esta interpretando mal los segundos, me explico,
esta es la sintaxis de write y el ultimo parámetro son la cantidad de bytes a escribir

```
size_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbytes);
```

Tu intentas mandar como parámetro segundos a la cadena pero la función pude estar recibiendo eso como los bytes, puedes intentar crear la cadena antes, ademas el primer parámetro debe ser un int (0: standard input, 1: standard output, 2: standard error).

Yo haría esto para evitar el problema de la cadena, espero te sirva.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(){
    uint64_t segundos;

    segundos = time(NULL);
    char *cadena = (char*)malloc(33 * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(cadena, "Segundos desde 1970: %" PRIu64 "\n", segundos);
    write(1, cadena, sizeof(char) * 33);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excelente, lo único es cambiar sprintf(cadena, "Segundos desde 1970: %" PRIu64 "\n", segundos); por sprintf(cadena, "Segundos desde 1970: %ld \n", (long int)segundos); para evitar la advertencia